# Same filename with different columns on each loop

Tags: dynamic, ssis, script-component, flatfilesource

I have a foreach loop that looks up the same filename but for each pass, the file gets populated differently with different columns. My flatfile source throws an error when it tries to read the new rebuilt file - Im kinda expecting that my recordset destination would also throw an error as well.

I'm using flatfile source and recordset destination. I'm thinking that I should just use another script task for this but if there's a way to make it work with these 2 tasks, that will be great

I wanted to reuse the same filename with different columns

Answer (score 0):

No if you are using a Dataflow in your foreach loop, then the same dataflow cannot be used to import a second file with different columns than the first.  The columns used in a dataflow are set at design time and cannot change at run time.